# Updating a ModelState's data with an auto-increment ID

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, auto-increment

I have a method that performs an insert into a table using Entity Framework 6. The table has an ID field that is populated automatically when it is written to SQL Server. I would like the method to return all of the data that was previously in the ModelState as well as the new record. When I run this code, I get everything except for the new record's ID, which comes back as a 0.

How can I rework this so it returns the new ID as well as the rest of the data from ModelState?

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EditingInline_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Book book)
    {
        if (bookViewModel != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MyRepository db = new MyRepository();
            db.Books.Add(book);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function Add return from db result of adding with correct id parameter.

Try this:

```
book = db.Book.Add(book);
```

It give you what you want.

If you want return model and modelstate use this:

```
return Json(new[] { book }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState);
```

Comment: That's all I was missing. It works great now, thanks!